# Fetch Get to PHP does not return response

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I have a simple application that fetches data from mysql and creates a table.
When i work on local the app works fine but once i have deployed it on a web hosting the fetch function does not return a response.

**JS**

```
async function getDataFromDB() {
    let endPoint= "getDataFromDB.php";
    dataFromDB= await fetch(endPoint, {
        method: 'get'
    });

    let response = await dataFromDB.json();

    createTable(response);
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$sql= "SELECT * FROM `lista_precios`";
$queryResult= mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Bad query: $sql");
$json_array= array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)){
    $json_array[] = $row;
};

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

?>

**LOCALHOST**
[image: Localhost]
[image]

** WEB HOSTING **
[image: Webhosting]

[image]

** SOLVED **

Finally i found a solution, the data was imported into de database from a CSV file y had to save the file as CSV UTF-8 and then in the php function encode each registry in UTF-8 before the json_encode. Otherwise it throws error.

Comment: Try your JS code with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com to see if it works.

Comment: I have tried it and it works.

Comment: If so, the problem is in your PHP code. But we can't check it.

Comment: Try to UTF-8 encode your PHP file.

Comment: I understand, but when i use it in localhost it works fine. There must be some server configuration i am missing.

Comment: I tried encoding utf-8 but did not work. I tried too `json_encode(utf8_encode($json_array))` and it returned null. At least it has returned something but it is not working

Comment: but both screenshots show response code 200...?

Comment: Yes it does not give any error but the response tabs is empty when working on the web server. I'll edit to include the image

Comment: And the live database does actually contain data?

Comment: Yes the data base contains data.

Comment: I have found out the problem is in this line `echo json_encode($json_array);` when data has º symbol. How could i fix it?